# 1 link in two paragraphs in html

Tags: html, wordpress, formatting

I'd like to have a link on text but the text is in 2 paragraphs (using the html editor) resulting in having 2 href's with the link i've given. Here's the regular code:

```
<p><a href="google.com">google</a></p>
<p><a href="google.com">dotcom</a></p>
```

and this is the result of this code how I don't want it to be:

[google](http://google.com)

[dotcom](http://google.com)

I just  want a single highlight when mousing over/clicking, I tried to manually changing the code with erasing the < /a > or so but since im a newbie when it comes to html nothing good came out...
Sorry for bad english, and thanks in advance for replies.[also why are html editors online so buggy? Like the one in wordpress.. trying to do a table exactly how you want it is so annoying.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried putting the `tag` around the p tags?

```html
<a href="#">
  <p>
    google
  </p>
  <p>
    dotcom
  </p>
</a>
```

In terms of usage, [HTML 5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element) states that the  element "may be wrapped around entire paragraphs, lists, tables, and so forth, even entire sections, so long as there is no interactive content within (e.g. buttons or other links)".

Comment: Okay, once I tagged it like you said, it works now, I tried to do it in online editor and link didn't appear but in wordpress it works so thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you accept the answer/upvote if everythings good, thatd be great :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<a href="google.com">
<p>Google</p>
<p>Dotcom</p>
</a>
```

Comment: please elaborate your answer, to prevent deletion!